# QT using namespaces, QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE vs using namespace

Tags: c++, qt, namespaces

I used following piece of code, and it compiles and works.

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE
using namespace QtDataVisualization;
```

I would like to ask:

1. I understand "using namespace xx"  but what does the other/upper one do?
2. Is there a way to use the same method for writing this? can anyone provide examples of following two options if possible off course?

a) putting both Ui and QtDataVisualization inside of QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE and QT_END_NAMESPACE?

b) use Ui and QtDataVisualization with method: "using namespace xx"

3. All links with help regarding this topic would be nice, i tried searching myself, cant find detailed explanations.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `using namespace` _imports_ stuff from a namespace into the current namespace (_e.g._ when you can't be bothered qualifying names so you just import them).  `namespace` makes a namespace current (_e.g._ any definitions or declarations will belong to that namespace, and namespace resolution uses that as the default qualifier).  These two things are very different.

Comment: Oh and since you asked for reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace